# print elements as list [ a, b, c]

Tags: python

I am creating this program that takes in a set of values which look like a tic tac toe game board in my function. then it prints out the the column number of each row (which the user specifies). however when I run the code it prints out like X 0 0 or something but is there a way to make it to print out like ['X', 'O', 'O'] with the brackets etc?

thanks

```
def get_column(board, col_num):
    """takes 3x3 game and returns 3 elemtn list containg all values from column number top to bottom"""

    print(board[0][col_num])
    print(board[1][col_num])
    print(board[2][col_num])

get_column( [['O', 'X', 'O'],
         ['X', ' ', ' '],
         ['X', ' ', ' ']], 2)
```

Comment: Try `pprint.pprint(board)` (you should first `import pprint`).

Comment: this is actually a problem for class and our class hasn't gone over that, so I doubt we'd have to use that.

Comment: I feel like my logic might just be wrong in general. If i have the output for col_num as 0  , it outputs the right x's and o's but also says 'None' on the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put everything you want to print into a list, then return the list.

```
def get_column(board, col_num):
    """takes 3x3 game and returns 3 elemtn list containg all values from column number top to bottom"""
    result = [board[0][col_num], board[1][col_num], board[2][col_num]]
    return result

print(get_column( 
    [['O', 'X', 'O'],
     ['X', ' ', ' '],
     ['X', ' ', ' ']], 2))
```

Comment: I get the right output but on the next line it also says 'None'?

Comment: I don't see that here: https://ideone.com/TuSFRe I think that's an artifact of the interactive Python you're using, it's showing the return value of `print()`, but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: that's what it shows me, and it's not letting me continue because it's 'wrong' https://imgur.com/a/BJaIZwm

Comment: What is that, a coding competition site? You probably shouldn't be printing the result, just returning it.